# Mocking vs Dependency Injection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking

I have written a Node.js module that uses the `fs` module, so I thought to test it, I should make the module not use it/use a mock module instead.

When looking for ways to do that I stumbled across two ways:

1. Dependency Injection: Giving my module a fake `fs` module when running tests, for example via a function parameter

> `function main(... , fs)`

2. Mocking: Using another piece of software while running tests that hacks into the process, and when the module require's the `fs` module gives it a different, fake module instead (eg using SinonJS)

Am I understanding things correctly? And how do I know when to use which way? Thanks.